# How do I test network performance between server and smart-devices

Tags: networking, performance, tcpip, comparison

I am currently working on a test use case where I need to test performance (benchmark) between a server/computer and smart-devices (tablet, smartphones etc.). The benchmark I want to do is based on LAN performance with normal TCP/IP sockets vs. WebSockets.

I am not quite sure where to begin, and I need to find a solution that fits both Android and iOS.

EDIT:
iperf seems to be the way to go with testing TCP and UDP performance, since there is applications for all platforms..

Answer (score 1):

Set up a mini [SpeedTest](http://www.speedtest.net/mini.php) server and you can do latency and transfer speed tests.

Comment: Great suggestion! But unfortunately i understand SpeedTest is based on SWF which is incompatible with iOS.

Comment: @JavaCake Mobile Apps :) http://www.speedtest.net/mobile.php

Comment: i might have been a little unclear. I need to make this test on LAN, and not internet, the SpeedTest mini server was a potential solution for this task.

Answer (score 1):

You could use iperf. There are Apps for [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.magicandroidapps.iperf&hl=en) and [iOS](http://iosiperf.wordpress.com/2011/12/19/ios-iperf-overview/)

Comment: I cannot really see if the Android app supports iperf v3 or not, else i need to stick to v2.

Comment: I assume its v2.0.5, 5$ well spend :-)

Comment: I can't tell which versions of iperf are supported sorry, I don't use it myself. 5$? In my play store it is free!

Comment: For iOS its unfortunately pricey, but the app seems to work. Do you by any chance have an suggestion for testing WebSockets?

Answer (score 1):

An old utility for testing TCP/UDP throughput is called [ttcp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ttcp). It was written by the same fellow who wrote ping. One host sets itself up as a receiver with `ttcp -rs` and the other host transmits to the receiver (default port 5001), with `ttcp -ts <receiver host>`. It's highly configurable, provides stats, and has been ported to multiple platforms.